# Raphael - How prevent the bubbling event on a set

Tags: events, raphael, event-bubbling

```
myset = paper.set();
myset.push(mycircle);
myset.push(mytext);
myset.mouseover(function(){ ... });
```

If I go upon item, or better on the text, the event takes it off.
What can I do to prevent that?

After some modify, now it works...

Comment: What do you mean by 'takes it of'?

Comment: Can you use this fiddle to decripe your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/YzN8K/6/

Comment: I mean that the event get it over.
Inside the circle there's a text, if I do mouseover on the text the event circle.mouseOUT is going to active, and I want prevent that.

Comment: I don't understand. In your description you assigned the mouseover to the set, not the text. A mouseout is not mentioned at all. Please enter your full code in the fiddle and fork it to us, or edit your description.

Comment: The code was that, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the CSS property pointer-events to none on the text element. E.g.

```
mytext.node.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
```

You need to do it via the node as this is not something directly supported by Rapahel so it will be ignored if you set it via mytext.attr directly.

Comment: Perfect!! Now I just asked how to write a custom event also (with another question)